# 3 dimensional matrix addition

Tags: python, matrix, addition

I have 3 matrices

```
A=[[[1,2,3]]]
B=[[[3,4,5]]]
```

and

```
C=[[[4,5,6]]]
```

i want to add these 3 matrices.
where the expected result is

```
A+B+C = [[[8,11,14]]]
```

please help me to solve this.

Comment: are these always one-dimensional matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
A=[[[1,2,3]]]
B=[[[3,4,5]]]
C=[[[4,5,6]]]
print [[map(sum, zip(A[0][0], B[0][0], C[0][0]))]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[[1,2,3]]])
>>> B = np.array([[[3,4,5]]])
>>> C = np.array([[[4,5,6]]])
>>> D = A+B+C
>>> D
array([[[ 8, 11, 14]]])
```